# Wordpress very slow due to database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

My Wordpress website is running locally on a `wamp64 3.1.9` installation with a `MySQL` server.  Wordpress has 1 theme with no additional plugins. Loading is fast with an empty database.

Yesterday I uploaded 7644 items in the database (taxonomies) and since then the website became significant slower. In the backend if I switch from plugin to dashboard or updates for example it takes about 45 seconds to load. If the database is empty it will load instantly.

Things I tried so far:

- Changed "localhost" into 127.0.0.1 for server name
  changed different
- Values like Key_buffer_size and others in the MySQL settings of WAMP
- Changed settings of PHP but not of Apache

The table `wp_term_taxonomy` is the one causing it to become very very slow

Comment: Values like...go on?  Changed what settings of PHP?

Comment: You really should work out what is slowing the system down - for example, use vmstat and top to check if its IO or CPU bound.   My guess is that you have a lot of swap and vm.swappiness is set to 60, so the system is swapping like mad when you want to show a page - but its just a guess.

Comment: Your question has multiple problems. First, WAMP should never be used for production - it's a dev tool that should be used for dev purposes and is off-topic here. Second, you give very little details to work on. Read [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608)

Comment: Then delete the question

Comment: @DGRL Hi, it got close because we lack info to help, please edit and it will be reopen to answer. Someone did a helpful post into your question in his free time to help, deleting the question now is not fair.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL's recommended InnoDB engine, then `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the one to raise.  If you are using the old MyISAM, then `key_buffer_size` is relevant.

Also, changes to the meta tables would help performance:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your help
I will look into this and try few things

The innodb_buffer_pool_size is 512MB and the key_buffer_size is 268MB

Comment: It not working 
does not matter how much memory i allocate 
loading time is around 45 seconds

Comment: @DGRL - How much available memory do you have?  Which engine are the table in?  Then see this for judging those two settings: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Comment: I found out that PHP_Xdebug was slowing down the site
After disabling this the loading time went from +45 sec. to around 6 sec.